# Android AdView/AdMob policies between activities and fragments

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, admob

My application has four different screens which will be encapsulated by fragments on one activity so that a constant AdView can display at the bottom of the application.  Only one fragment will be displayed at a time, along with the ad.

In one of these application fragments however, there's quite a bit of dragging and clicking which I'm afraid will lead to false ad clicks, so I want to remove the ad fragment when that particular application fragment is in use.

My question is - is this as simple as destroying the AdView when this fragment is selected and bringing it back when the user leaves that fragment?  The reason I'm curious is that I didn't know if AdMob would flag my account - does an entirely new ad load every time I instantiate the AdView?  I'm just afraid that AdMob would see this as me trying to load/unload a bunch of AdViews to cycle through more ads.

So - let's say an ad is set to display for 60s.  The user starts the application and gets an ad at t=0s.  The user then moves into the no-ad screen at t=3s, and then back to an ad-displaying screen at t=24s.  On the move back to the screen with the ad, does a new ad load?  Or is this managed by AdMob to keep the ad rate constant regardless of how many requests you make in an ad's time interval?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new AD loads according to the frequency you have set in Admob and if the user does not see the AD or click on the AD then you will not get any revenue(ofcourse :-) ). Best option is to set the AD on the top or bottom of the screen so that the user does not click them accidentally.